# Rails migrations: What are the advantages of "up" and "down" versus "change"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am reading https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html and ask myself what the advantages of having an "up" and a "down" method in a migration file over doing a migration via a "change" method.

I could imagine that that way via a "down" method arbitrary migrations become rollback'able. On the other hand, there may still be other migrations that depend on the migration which aren't handled even if you have a "down" method.

So is it correct, that having "up" and "down" methods instead of a "change" method does NOT enable you to rollback arbitrary migration files ?

Second: The rails guide speaks of

```
you can also use the old style of migration using up and down methods instead of the change method.
```

Does that mean the up/down schematism is deprecated?

Does it have any other advantages over a "change" method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand this, change method knows how to reverse itself automatically. Up does not so you have to specify reverse functionality by yourself in down method.

Automatical reversing comes with downsides as it does not know how to reverse all the available migration calls. Source for this and full list of auto reverse methods is available in the official docs [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method).

To more clearly answer your question - advatage of "up" and "down" over "change" is being able to have fine control over the way migration gets executed and reverted. Bare in mind this does not mean you can't do all your migrations with up/down or that it's deprecated but you lose out on the conveniece provided by "change". For summary:

- Change - For majority of migrations
- Change + reversible - For some complexity not supported by "change" method"
- up/down - For fine control. Very nieche, custom or complex migrations.

Comment: Thanks ! I chose your answer as accepted answer! 

So generally do you only need "down" if you want fine control over how the migration is rolledback, right? For most usecases the `change` method is sufficient, as rails does automatically know how to reverse the changes made by the method, correct ?

Comment: Exactly. The link to using the change method I provided has a list of migration definitions ActiveRecord knows how to revert so as long as you stick to that list, you should be good with "change".